# Variable levels of smoothing within the same Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, smoothing

I currently have a large matrix `M` (~100x100x50 elements) containing both positive and negative values.  At the moment, if I want to smooth this matrix, I use the `smooth3` function to apply a gaussian kernel over the entire 3-D matrix.

What I want to achieve is a variable level of smoothing within this matrix - i.e.. different parts of the matrix `M` are smoothed to different levels of sigma depending of the value in a similar 3-D matrix, `d` (with values ranging from 0 to 1).  Where `d` is 0, no smoothing occurs, where `d` is 1 a maximum level of smoothing occurs.

The fact that the matrix is 3-D is trivial.  Smoothing in 3 dimensions is nice, but not essential, and my current code (performing various other manipulations) handles each of the 50 slices of `M` separately anyway.  I am happy to replace `smooth3` with a convolution of `M` with a gaussian function, and perform this convolution over each slice individually.  What I can't figure out is how to vary the sigma level of this gaussian function (based on `d`) given its location in `M` and output the result accordingly.

An alternative approach may be to use matrix `d` as a mask for a very smooth version of matrix `Ms` and somehow manipulate `M` and `Ms` to give an equivalent result, however I'm not convinced that this will work as I can't think of a function to combine `M` and `Md` that won't give artefacts of each of `M` or `Ms` when 0 < `d` < 1...any thoughts?

[I'm using 2009b, and only have access to the Signal Processing toolbox.]

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at the Guided Image Filter. It is a computationally efficient generalization of the bilateral filter.

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/jiansun/papers/guidedfilter_eccv10.pdf

It will allow you to do proper smoothing based on your guidance matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the paper - interesting reading.  The paper seems to implicitly imply that the input image is made up of positive values, but I can't work out if this method will work with an input image that has positive and negative values?

Comment: If you fear that, why not shift the values to a positive range for smoothing?

Comment: That's true, and I've since tried this using the code by He et al. on a small 9x9 matrix and my full size matrix, but this is a non-linear filtering method - I don't see that you can correctly recover values post smoothing by simply reversing an initial linear operation...?